# Polarization vector of dielectric electrostatics

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electricity

I know two laws for Polarization vector of a dielectric material
$$\vec P = N q \vec{\Delta L}$$
Where $N$ is the number of dipoles per meter cube, $\vec{\Delta L}$ is the vector that represents the distance between the two charges of the dipole. It seems from this equation that the polarization vector isn't dependent on the magnitude of the electric field.

The second equation is
$$\vec P = \varepsilon\gamma \vec E,$$
and from this equation the polarization vector depends on both the magnitude and the direction of the electric field.

I thought that this must mean that there is one quantity in the first equation that depends on the magnitude of the electric field but I can't tell whether it is $N$ or $\| \vec{\Delta L\|}$. Could someone help me understand which of these variables depends on the electric field, and what the dependence is?

Answer (score 1):

In the first equation $\Delta L$ itself is typically proportional to $E$.  That establishes the connection between the two formulas.

However, $\Delta L$ might not be proportional to $E$.  It might be permanent.  The first equation allows for this case, but the second does not.  If $\Delta L$ is permanent,  the material has a permanent electric dipole moment.  But this is uncommon, or at best the permanent dipole moment is small.  For practical purposes, polarizations are *induced* by an electric field.  Thus the second equation is more commonly seen in practice.

Comment: By permanent, do you mean if the dipole is polar?
If that is true then does a polar material has a constant polarization vector which doesn't change with the magnitude of an external electric field ?

Comment: You specified a dielectric *material* not a dielectric *molecule*.   The polarization of a material is an *average* polarization over a microscopically large but macroscopically small volume.  This is called the *macroscopic polarization*.  In most materials that are made up of polar molecules the dipoles are arranged randomly, or in such a way that the dipoles cancel each other. The average permanent polarization is zero.  A few materials do have permanent polarizations.  They are called [*ferroelectric* materials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Ferroelectric_materials).

Comment: I think I misread your comment.  "Permanent" means "having a macroscopic polarization at zero field".  The polarization can still respond to an applied field.

Comment: so for those materials that have permanent polarization vector $\vec{\Delta L}$ doesn't depend on the external electric field ?

Comment: No, $\Delta L$ does depend on $E$, but in a very complicated way.  The response is not linear.

Answer (score 1):

The first equation is the definition of the polarisation field.

The second equation is not a definition and is only true in limited circumstances - those dielectric materials where the polarisation is indeed linearly dependent and in the same direction as the applied electric field.

The connection between the two in those materials where this is true, is that the dipole separation is in the same direction as, and increases linearly with, the electric field.

Answer (score 0):

The first expression refers to definition of polarization in terms of density of physical electric dipoles.

The second expression refers to (approximate) physical law, which says the polarization is proportional to total electric strength.

Comment: So according to the first equation does the polarization vector depend on the magnitude of the electric field or not ?

Comment: There is no electric field in the definition, so of course the definition alone implies nothing about dependence of polarization on the electric field.

Comment: The dependence of polarization on the electric field is a physical law. For dielectrics, the polarization is approximately linear function of electric field.